# Debugging Adblockers

Tags: iframe, embed, adblock

My website offers an **iframe** that can be embedded in other websites.
The problem is that it is being blocked by adblocks, both in Firefox and in Chrome.

The question is very simple: how can I debug adblocks and understand why it is blocked?
Can't find information on the web.